# How to convert a PCL-file using GhostPCL (gpcl6win64) without left white margin to PDF

Tags: pdf, converters, pcl

I am converting a PCL-file to PDF using GhostPCL (ghostpcl-9.56.1-win64) using the following command line:

```
gpcl6win64.exe -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sPAPERSIZE=a4 -r300x300 -o gpcl6win64-test-see-page-3.pdf gpcl6win64-test-see-page-3.pcl
```

The resulting PDF seems to be cut at the left side of each and every page.
It looks like the following:[Left side is cut away, marked yellow here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/22NYw.png)

When I use another tool to show PCL, I get:

[PCL file itself seems to be ok](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZWn1B.png)

How can I convert the file while keeping it complete?

I uploaded the original PCL-file, the resulting PDF and the two images to https://filebin.net/ytxzfkpr0b90wgwf

The problem arises at page 3 of the PCL-file, please just ignore the other pages (I didn't manage to remove them from PCL)

Comment: Rendering the input file to a bitmap shows the same white area, so it is nothing to do with the pdfwrite device.  If you are convinced the output is incorrect then you should open a bug report.

Comment: Thanks. My suspect is that it is more a problem when parsing the PCL-file - maybe to be consistent with the PCL-typical area that some printers can not use/access, when no option such like "edge2egde" is activated.
So: is there an option/switch that needs to be set to get "edge2edge"?

Comment: The interpretation is my point exactly; the rendering is the same so it's not the pdfwrite device, but the way the file is interpreted. I am not a PCL expert so I am not able to decide from the PCL file if the output is correct or possibly device-dependent (different PCL printers do not all behave the same way). You can check the docs for options, but I certainly don't know of anything. The devices in the Ghostscript family don't implement hardware margins so it's unlikely to be that. If you think the behaviour is incorrect you should open a bug report and someone knowledgeable will look at it

Comment: Thanks. I did not find an option that points into this direction, when reading PCL; for PDF there seem to be some types of boxes to use. I will file a bugreport, if I get no help here :-)

Comment: @K J: Thanks for your hint. And yes, the viewer that shows that the PCL-file is complete and not somehow cropped, was Compart DocBridge View.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I found the solution to this, you need to inform on PCL file the paper size with the command [ESC]&l26A , so ghostpcl will identify on PCL file the paper size and will make the pdf file using A4 sizes.

Comment: Thanks - I will check to see, if I your solution works for me